# Paypal certificate error. PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: paypal, openssl

I need help. I'm trying to update a certificate used for paypal but I'm getting an error (see below).

I am following the steps provided by paypal seen here: https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_encryptedwebpayments#id08A3I0P20E9.

Here is the error:

```
PHP Exception

A PHP exception has occured!

Could not sign data: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
Please check your configuration.
```

I have done this successfully in the past on the same server following the same steps.  I have no idea whats going on.  Does this mean anything to anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  The path to the certificate was invalid and the error was because the cert file could not be found.

It took me forever to figure this out because I was simply updating an existing certificate that had expired so all I was doing was replacing the file.  The cert file I was replacing was named my-pubcert.pem which worked fine for a few years but for whatever reason it wasn't working now.  All I did was rename the file to something else and it worked.

Pretty dumb, no idea why that occurred and frustrated that I wasted so much time trying to figure out such a simple thing.  Hopefully this helps someone in the future.